# Como descobrir a versão do C# que eu estou usando?

Tags: c#

Queria saber como faço para descobrir a versão do C# que eu estou usando.

Comment: Painel de controle => programas e recursos :D

Comment: @Articuno é sério isso?

Comment: Isso é a versão do .net framework. Não???

Comment: @WallaceMaxters uma coisa que não ficou claro é se você quer saber se é o Vs, durante a execução, ou outra forma

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É possível verificar a versão através de código também:

```
string version = typeof(string).Assembly.ImageRuntimeVersion;
```

> Porém, pelo o que estava analisando, a versão informada pelo
> `ImageRuntimeVersion` não é a versão correta do C#.

A versão do C# depende de qual .NET Framework você está utilizando.

- **C# 1.0** lançado com .NET 1.0 e VS2002
- **C# 1.2** lançado com .NET 1.1 e VS2003
- **C# 2.0** lançado com .NET 2.0 e VS2005
- **C# 3.0** lançado com .NET 3.5 e VS2008
- **C# 4.0** lançado com .NET 4 e VS2010
- **C# 5.0** lançado com .NET 4.5 e VS2012
- **C# 6.0** lançado com .NET 4.6 e VS2015
- **C# 7.0** lançado com .NET 4.6.2 e VS2017
- **C# 7.1** lançado com com VS2017 v15.3
- **C# 7.2** lançado com VS2017 v15.5
- **C# 7.3** lançado com VS2017 v15.7
- **C# 8.0** lançado com o .NET Core 3.0 e VS2019 16.3
- **C# 9.0** lançado com o .NET 5 e VS2019 16.8
- **C# 10.0** lançado com o .NET 6 e VS2022 17.0
- **C# 11.0** lançado com o .NET 7 e VS2022 17.4

O Time da Linguagem C# criou um histórico das versões do C# e suas funcionalidades no repositório `github` deles:

- [Histórico de Versões C#](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/Language-Version-History.md)

Informações retiradas de:

- [Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247621/what-are-the-correct-version-numbers-for-c/247623#247623)

Answer (score 5):

- Clique no arquivo de projeto (geralmente um csproj) com o botão direito
- Properties
- Build
- Advanced
- Na seção *general* tem *language version*

[image]

Comment: Caramba! não tem csproj no Webforms :\

Comment: Mas tem um arquivo de projeto

Comment: Não seria clicar com o botão direito no projeto, Properties e na aba application conferir o target framework?

Comment: A versão do "Target Framework" está como ".Net Framework 4.5". Mas tem alguma relação com a versão do C#? (fiquei na dúvida agora)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Não tem

Comment: Selecionando um projeto da sua solução e seguir os passos que o @LINQ passou, você consegue verificar a versão do C# sim, acabei de fazer o teste.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Não. Não existe relação direta entre a versão da linguagem e do framework.

Answer (score 4):

Até onde eu sei não há informação em tempo de execução, só consegue pegar do *framework*.

O Compilador diz a versão dele se chamar em linha de comando. Mas não diz qual a versão da linguagem, porque ele pode compilador com um perfil de versão diferente. Dá para pelo menos saber até que versão ele compila.

Tente fazer isto no projeto:

[image: Linguagem da projeto]

Se nada disso der certo, e tem que dar, experimenta usar um recurso que só tem em uma determinada versão, se funcionar sabe que pelo menos aquele versão está ok. Se der erro sabe que tem uma versão mais baixa, aí vai na tentativa e erro pra cima ou pra baixo :) Eu sei que é gambi, mas é a forma se nada mais der certo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/865579/How-to-change-targeted-Csharp-version-in-Visual-St